# Testing React: Target Container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, tdd

I'm attempting to test a React component with Jest/Enzyme while using Webpack.

I have a very simple test @

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import App from './App';

it('App', () => {
  const app = shallow(<App />);
  expect(1).toEqual(1);
});
```

The relative component it's picking up is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

// import './styles/normalize.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>app</div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

However, running `jest` causes a failure:

`Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.`

With errors @

`at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.js:14:48)
at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:4:38)`

The test files references line 4, which is the import of `<App />`, that causes a fail. The stack trace says line 14 of `App.js` is the reason for the failure -- which is nothing more than the render call from `react-dom`, something I've never had a challenge with (the app renders properly from my Webpack setup).

For those interested (Webpack code):

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/App',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: './dist'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "tic-tac-dux",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --inline --hot --content-base dist/",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "^.+\\.(css|sass)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-jest": "^16.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.4.1",
    "jest": "^16.0.1",
    "jest-cli": "^16.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
  }
}
```

Oh, and if anyone is going to say that the div element isn't being loaded before the script, here's my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What could be the reason for this peculiar rendering problem? Something to do with a new Jest update to 15.0?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`App.jsx` is supposed to export the App class and do nothing more, `render` should be called elsewhere.

If you remove the `render` call from the App.jsx error should disappear, it pops up because the test environment doesn't supply the DOM with an `app` id.

Comment: i got same error:- 

i am tested with ava ..

pls tell me where should i wrong..

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
 render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Index} />
        <Route path="page1" component={Page1} />
        <Route path="page2" component={Page2} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('app'));

Comment: @BhavikKheni Please, create new question and include your complete code along with the error and stack trace there.

Comment: Where should it be called if not if not in App.jsx?

Answer (score 60):

For anyone else that was combing through the internet like I've been - looking for a solution to this when testing with Jest - I will back up the answer by @biphobe by saying Jest will cause this error to occur when you export something inside the same file that is calling ReactDOM.render.

In my case, I was exporting an object within my index.js where I was also calling ReactDOM.render. I removed this export and voila!

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.  The explicit mention of calling `ReactDOM.render()` was precisely what I needed to understand the  exact issue!

Comment: Glad it was helpful!

Comment: im having a similar issue when trying to import actions in my test. Unfortunately removing ReactDom does not help

Comment: @PraveenSrinivasan I was running in to problems with Jest when I tried to both call ReactDOM.render and export something within the same javascript file.

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks. I added an export of an object to my entry file that uses `ReactDom.render`. But there are no tests for that file yet.

Comment: Thanks! Same issue happened to me. Spent ~2 hours on this until I've found your comment.
Out of curiosity, any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 35):

As I see, this error arises in many cases and requires different approaches to solve it. My scenario is not the same as the example above, I use **redux & router**, although I was struggling with the same error. What helped me to solve this problem is to change `index.js` from:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppRouter />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

to:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    (<Provider store={store}>
        <AppRouter/>
    </Provider>),
     document.getElementById('root') || document.createElement('div') // for testing purposes
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: very helpful answer -- frustrating though because I can't figure out if this is the supported way; I wonder if it's because we're using Provider?

Comment: changing from "double quotes"  to 'single quotes' worked for me, thank you!!

Comment: @bibangamba I'm surprised that matters. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 12):

**I found a solution for this error to my use case: Using the same Redux store React is using outside of React.**

In trying to export my React's Redux `store` from `index.tsx` to be used somewhere else outside of the React application, I was getting the same error while running Jest tests (which make use of Enzyme) in the `App.tsx` file.

### The error

The initial code that didn't work when testing React looked like this.

```js
// index.tsx

import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from "redux";
import App from "./components/App";
import { rootReducer } from "./store/reducers";
import { initialState } from "./store/state";

const middlewares = [];

export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)),
);

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root"),
);
```

### The solution that worked for me

Separate the Redux store logic into a new file named `store.ts`, then create a `default export` (to be used by `index.tsx`, i.e., the React application) and a non-default export with `export const store` (to be used from non-React classes), as follows.

```js
// store.ts

import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from "redux";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import { rootReducer } from "./store/reducers";
import { initialState } from "./store/state";

const middlewares = [];

export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)),
);

export default store;
```

```js
// updated index.tsx

import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import App from "./components/App";
import store from "./store";

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root"),
);
```

### Using the Redux store in non-React classes

```js
// MyClass.ts

import { store } from "./store"; // store.ts

export default class MyClass {
  handleClick() {
    store.dispatch({ ...new SomeAction() });
  }
}
```

### The `default` export

A small note before you go. Here is how to use the `default` and the non-default exports.

- `default export store;` is used with `import store from "./store";`
- `export const store = ...` is used with `import { store } from "./store";`

Hope this helps!

https://nono.ma/says/solved-invariant-violation-target-container-is-not-a-dom-element

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the creation of two stores?

Comment: Can't we use `import store from "./store";` in our non-React files? Thus, avoiding the need of non-default export in store.ts

Comment: Thanks for your question @IvOv. I wrote this a year ago and that seems to be the whole point. I would have to test it again but as far as I can recall accessing the same store than React was accessing wasn't working for me and that's why I had to use this workaround.

Comment: This solved it for me!!
Thank you so much for this solution :)
question about this solution, if we import "stores" both in  "MyClass.ts" and both in "index.ts" isnt that mean that were calling createStore() twice?

Thanks! 
@Nono

Comment: This was it for me.  It involved a bit of refactoring to remove the `store` creation from index.tsx, but once I moved that into its own file, and imported from there, the test passed.  Why doesn't jest like a store that is exported from index.tsx/js?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure in your test file you have well imported the *render* component.
It should be imported from `@testing-library/react` not from `react-dom`:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
```

Answer (score 2):

Well we cant stop the developers from exporting component from any file and test it in isolation even if it have a ***react-dom*** import or usage in it .I mean what's wrong  in it . We are not trying to disturb the whole file and test out some pieces of it as long as that is a valid piece of code .

Jest does not have an issue with ***react-dom*** , however conceptually they are diff . Jest is supposedly a browserless virtual test environment . React-DOM is a library which does the stitching of virtual DOM to real DOM for react components .
So obvious enough we can/should not test it in a normal way . But that is not the discussion for now. we are fine as long as our exported components are testable .

**So Lets mock it**

I did the mock in the testSetup file configured with "setupFilesAfterEnv" in [jest config](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration) .

```
jest.mock("react-dom", () => {
    return ({
        "render": jest.fn()
    })
})
```

That is pretty much worked for me. My react and react-dom code now happily go together in one file , works in browser and in the testing environment as well .

I have not encountered any issues because of this . If there is any I will be looking into the comment section

Comment: I add this to my `request.test.tsx`, then all my tests in the file passed. But some other test files failed. So I applied @Dani Alcala's answer. And all tests passed now.
Note: `request.test.tsx` is an encapsulation of `axios`

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me. Just render if the element is there:

```
const root = document.getElementById('root');
if (root) {
    render(
        <App />,
        root,
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out this error can also be thrown when working with `Portals` in your tests. If you want to skip the error you can either `mock` `Portals` or add the `Portal` container element in your render method:

```js
render (
  <div>
    <TestedComponent />
    <div id="portal" />
  </div>
)
```