# Jest/Enzyme w/ React - "Target container is not a DOM element."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test that a button in a certain react component triggers a function in its parent component. I stumble upon my issue right when I import the component in my test file, so the test hasn't even run yet.

The component I import is a regular react component and is exported as:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Manager);
```

And in my test file I import it as:

```
import Manager from '../index.js';
```

When I run the test I get:

```
Target container is not a DOM element.
```

I know this is very little information to give but there is literally nothing else relevant as far as I can see. The component I'm testing does a bunch of things and has a render function. After **a lot** of reading I read that some people had a similar issue because they exported something in the same file that does `ReactDOM.render`. Unfortunately, this does not apply to my problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your index.js doesn't try to call `ReactDOM.render`?

Comment: Does this answer help you with your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42611909/1695393 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing React: Target Container is not a DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39986178/testing-react-target-container-is-not-a-dom-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an additional export without `connect` in your `Manager` and then you'll be able to import it in your test file and test its behavior:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Manager);
export { Manager };
```

Then in your test file:

```
import { Manager } from 'your-path'; // now a named import without Connect
```

Answer (score 2):

Might have a render call somewhere in your index.js file.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, please refrain from these answers, till you have the possibility (ie enough reputation) to comment on posts...